# Why was the 'hiccup girl' on trial for murder and not accessory

Tags: sentencing

so I was watching the new Piers Morgan documentary about a young girl, who helped set up a robbery for her boyfriend.
She was not directly involved in the robbery, wasn't there and didn't know the participants had a gun, yet she was charged with first degree murder and given a life sentence without the possibility of parole in a Florida court.
My question is why wasn't she charged with accessory to robbery or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Florida has [felony murder](http://statelaws.findlaw.com/florida-law/florida-first-degree-murder-laws.html) laws. If you participate (including being an accessory) in the specified list of felonies (including armed robbery) and a murder is committed in the course of that felony, you are guilt of first degree murder. It is a prerequisite that she would *also* have been convicted for the robbery.

Comment: There probably wouldn't have to have been a distinct conviction for the robbery, but there would have to be proof that she committed the elements of robbery beyond a reasonable doubt and that somebody involved committed murder, admittedly a subtle distinction.